# Error: right operand of <= has wrong type when using vector

Tags: c++

I want to make a program know the smallest number ever seen and the largest 
number ever seen. This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>;
#include<vector>:
#include<algorithm>


using namespace std;


int main(){
vector<double>number;
double x;
while (cin >> x){
    number[0] =x ;

    number.push_back(x);


}
for (int y=0; y <= number.size; y++){
    sort(number.begin(), number.end());
    if (number[y] >= number[0]){
        cout << "the largest so far\n";
    }
    else if (number[y] >= number[number.size()/2]){
        cout << "the smalest so far \n";
    }
    else{
        cout << x;
    }
 }
}
```

Every time I run the code it shows this error:

```
 error C2297: '<=' : illegal, right operand has type 'unsigned int              

 (__thiscall std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>::* )(void) throw() const' 
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Ty=double
    1>          ]
```

I try to fix it but I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: `size` is a member function but you're accessing it like it's a value.

Comment: FWIW, GCC and Clang give really reasonable error messages here.

Comment: If you want to find out if you're the tallest person in the world, you only need to compare yourself to the tallest known person, not to everybody. You don't need a vector for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the right operand of your operator `<=` should be an `unsigned int`.

This means you have a problem with `number.size`. In fact, `size()` is a member function of the class `vector` and thus, should be written as follow: `number.size()`

```
for (int y=0; y < number.size; y++) {/*...*/}
```

Also note that the index of the `vector` start at `0` and go to `size() - 1`. So you should use `<` and not `<=`

Some other comments:

If you want to sort your `vector`, you can do it outside of the `for` loop since you are not modifying your vector outside of the loop, once is enough.

Regarding your algorithm itself, I am not sure what kind of output you are trying to achieve exactly. But, since your vector will be sorted, the smallest number will be `number[0]` and the biggest `number[number.size()-1]`

Note also that you have some `algorithm` functions that can help you achieve your goal without even sorting your vector: [`std::min_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) & [`std::max_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

Comment: Since you write how to use it correctly, then you should do so in the loop as well. Also fix the off by one error `<=` vs `<`.

Comment: thank you very much for the information finally i fix my code
Honestly i'm a very beginner programmer and i learn Programming from a book so thank you